# How to install pygame without error: metadata-generation-failed?

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I already try a lot of tips and still get this error while installing pygame, I have python 3.11 and tried to switch to 3.9 with the same result

Install command: pip3 install pygame

Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [32 lines of output]

```
  WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
  Using Darwin configuration...
  
  /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
  /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
  /bin/sh: sdl2-config: command not found
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "/private/var/folders/j0/jkd60bqs5blcvy0t1_4r47sw0000gn/T/pip-install-ho52d8jb/pygame/setup.py", line 359, in <module>
      buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/private/var/folders/j0/jkd60bqs5blcvy0t1_4r47sw0000gn/T/pip-install-ho52d8jb/pygame/buildconfig/config.py", line 225, in main
      deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/private/var/folders/j0/jkd60bqs5blcvy0t1_4r47sw0000gn/T/pip-install-ho52d8jb/pygame/buildconfig/config_darwin.py", line 132, in main
      [DependencyProg('SDL', 'SDL_CONFIG', 'sdl2-config', '2.0', ['sdl'])],
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "/private/var/folders/j0/jkd60bqs5blcvy0t1_4r47sw0000gn/T/pip-install-ho52d8jb/pygame/buildconfig/config_unix.py", line 39, in __init__
      self.ver = config[0].strip()
                 ~~~~~~^^^
  IndexError: list index out of range
  
  ---
  For help with compilation see:
      https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
  To contribute to pygame development see:
      https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
  ---
  
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> pygame

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with switch python version to 3.9 and installing pip older version

Comment: This is a comment, but not an answer